# Problem speeding up report rendering with FastReports

Tags: c#, fastreport

I'm working on report rendering with FastReports - I'm doing this coming from a system to render with Crystal Reports. When using Crystal, I found that preloading a report and then binding parameters on request sped up crystal dramatically, since most of the time for a small layout like an invoice is in the setup. I'm now trying to achieve the same with FastReports.

It's unclear how much time setup takes however, so I'd also be interested in whether this is not a worthwhile endeavour.

My issue is that I have used a JSON API call, and used ConnectionStringExpression with a single parameter. In a nutshell, changing the parameter does not reload the data when I call Prepare.

Here's my code, with the second report load taken out, it renders the same report twice.

```
        var report = new Report();
        report.Load("C:\\dev\\ia\\products\\StratusCloud\\AppFiles\\Reports\\SalesQuoteItems.frx");

        var urlTemplate = "http://localhost:9502/data/sales-quote/{CardCode@}/{DocEntry@}";
        var reportParms = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
        reportParms.Add("CardCode@", "C20000");
        reportParms.Add("DocEntry@", 77);

        var connectionstring = "Json=" + System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(urlTemplate, "{([^}]+)}", (m) => {
            if (reportParms.ContainsKey(m.Groups[1].Value))
            {
                return string.Format("{0}", reportParms[m.Groups[1].Value]);
            }
            return m.Value;
        });
        var dataapiparm = report.Dictionary.Parameters.FindByName("DataAPIUrl@");
        if (dataapiparm != null)
        {
            dataapiparm.Value = connectionstring;
        }
        foreach(FastReport.Data.Parameter P in report.Dictionary.Parameters)
        {
            if (reportParms.ContainsKey(P.Name))
            {
                P.Value = reportParms[P.Name];
            }
        }
        report.Prepare();

        var pdfExport = new PDFSimpleExport();
        pdfExport.Export(report, "test1.pdf");


        //report = new Report();
        //report.Load("C:\\dev\\ia\\products\\StratusCloud\\AppFiles\\Reports\\SalesQuoteItems.frx");
        reportParms["DocEntry@"] = 117;

        connectionstring = "Json=" + System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(urlTemplate, "{([^}]+)}", (m) => {
            if (reportParms.ContainsKey(m.Groups[1].Value))
            {
                return string.Format("{0}", reportParms[m.Groups[1].Value]);
            }
            return m.Value;
        });

        dataapiparm = report.Dictionary.Parameters.FindByName("DataAPIUrl@");
        if (dataapiparm != null)
        {
            dataapiparm.Value = connectionstring;
        }
        foreach (FastReport.Data.Parameter P in report.Dictionary.Parameters)
        {
            if (reportParms.ContainsKey(P.Name))
            {
                P.Value = reportParms[P.Name];
            }
        }

        report.Prepare();

        pdfExport.Export(report, "test2.pdf");
```

Cheers,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Fast Project definitely doesn't recalculate the ConnectionStringExpression on report.Prepare, so I went back to another method that I was looking at. It turns out that if the ConnectionString itself is rewritten, then report.Prepare does refetch the data.

A simple connection string without a schema takes a long time to process, so I remove everything beyond the semi-colon and keep it, replace the url portion of the connectionstring, and then stick teh same schema information back on the end.

Copying the schema information into each report generation connection string seems to remove around 10 seconds from report.Prepare!

At the moment it's the best that I can do, and I wonder if there is another more efficient method of rerunning the same report against new data (having the same schema).